# Download multiple files using SourcePollingChannelAdapter- start/stop issue?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-integration-sftp

My requirement is to donwload multiple files from a remote directory in a file server in my spring-batch application. One of the example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/sftp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/sftp/SftpInboundReceiveSample.java)  suggests the usage of SourcePollingChannelAdapter. In this example the adapter is started adapter.start() but its not stopped. So how does the lifecycle of this work ? My requirement is to first download & Only when all files are downloaded, then proceed to read the files. But this seems this is kind of async process to download the files. So how would I get notified when all the files are downloaded & ready to proceed further ? I dont see any other methods to inject any handlers to the adapter/pollablechannel.

Sample config used :

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapterBean"
        auto-startup="false" channel="receiveChannelBean" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        local-directory="${sftp.download.localDirResource}"
        remote-directory="${sftp.download.remoteFilePath}"
        auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="false"
        filename-regex=".*\.csv$">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="5000" max-messages-per-poll="3"  />
    </int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="receiveChannelBean">
        <int:queue/>
    </int:channel>
```

It throws InterruptedException if adapter.stop() is called explicitly. If stop is not called , the files are downloaded in async way without blocking & hence the next step doesn't know if the download is completed or is in-progress.

EDIT : Code Snippet of DownloadingTasklet

```
 @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        try {

            sftpInbondAdapter.start();
            Thread.sleep(15000); // ---Is this mandatory ?
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BatchClientException("Batch File Download was un-successful !", e);
        } finally {
           // sftpInbondAdapter.stop();
            Logger.logDebug("BATCH_INPUT_FILE_DOWNLOAD", "COMPLETED");
        }
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` works in two phases:

- First of all it does synchronization from the remote directory to the local one:

  ```
  Message<File> message = this.fileSource.receive();
  if (message == null) {
      this.synchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(this.localDirectory);
      message = this.fileSource.receive();
  }
  ```
- And as you see only after that it starts to emit files as a messages. But already only local files. So, download from the FTP has been done already.
- The next download attempt happens only when all local files are cleared during sending process.

So, what you want is a built-in functionality.

**EDIT**

Some DEBUG logs from our tests:

```
19:29:32,005 DEBUG task-scheduler-1 util.SimplePool:190 - Obtained new org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@26f16625.
19:29:32,036 DEBUG task-scheduler-1 inbound.SftpInboundFileSynchronizer:287 - cannot copy, not a file: /sftpSource/subSftpSource
19:29:32,036 DEBUG task-scheduler-1 session.CachingSessionFactory:187 - Releasing Session org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@26f16625 back to the pool.
19:29:32,036 DEBUG task-scheduler-1 util.SimplePool:221 - Releasing org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@26f16625 back to the pool
19:29:32,037 DEBUG task-scheduler-1 inbound.SftpInboundFileSynchronizer:270 - 3 files transferred
19:29:32,037 DEBUG task-scheduler-1 file.FileReadingMessageSource:380 - Added to queue: [local-test-dir\rollback\ sftpSource1.txt, local-test-dir\rollback\sftpSource2.txt]
19:29:32,043  INFO task-scheduler-1 file.FileReadingMessageSource:368 - Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=local-test-dir\rollback\ sftpSource1.txt, headers={id=40f75bd1-2150-72a4-76f0-f5c619a246da, timestamp=1465514972043}]]
```

It is with config like:

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter
        session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        channel="requestChannel"
        remote-directory="/sftpSource"
        local-directory="local-test-dir/rollback"
        auto-create-local-directory="true"
        local-filter="acceptOnceFilter">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1" max-messages-per-poll="0"/>
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Pay attention how it shows `3 files transferred`, where one of them is directory, so skipped.

How it says `Added to queue:`

And only after that it starts to emit them as messages.

And everything is just because I have `fixed-delay="1"`. Even if it is only 1 millisecond.

The `max-messages-per-poll="0"` means processes everything with one polling task.

Comment: can you share more information . Are you saying the requirement cannot be achieved using this adapter or should I increase any timeouts to allow more time for localDir sync.?

Comment: I show you existing code which is just blocking. Although I can guess that you use there `fixed-rate`, which starts a new task not waiting for  finish of the previous one. So, change your `<poller>` to use `fixed-delay` and the process will be single threaded. Therefore no any file will be emitted until the full download.

Comment: Right, that samples uses `fixed-rate`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/sftp/src/test/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/SftpInboundReceiveSample-context.xml#L35. That really might not be enough to wait for the entire download from the FTP.

Comment: Still fixed-delay doesnt help. Should I call receive() explicitly  ? If so how many times as we don't know the no.of files present

Comment: You have to clean local directory before each test :-)

Comment: ok even If I clear the local directory , not all the files are downloaded. only 4 out of 10 are downloaded. Any time out config needed ? Should I call receive() explicitly ? If so how many times as we don't know the no.of files present

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe you have several components for the same local directory? What you say just does not make sense for the single-threaded, blocking code above.

Comment: It is because, my batch process ends before all the files are downloaded & this doesn't seem to be a blocking call giving the flow to wait until it completes. Any handler/callback ?

Comment: However, If I wait after starting the adapter for few seconds, the download process starts & downloads. So there is not provision to make the flow wait ?

Comment: It isn't blocking for `main` because it is done in the separate `Thread`. You have to block `main` manually.

Comment: ok. Thats a bit risky as it might end up in long waits. Even If its done, how long to make the main() wait ? any notifier or any estimate?

Comment: I need to know the rest of your application. My point to block the `main` until some signal to exit from the app. Everything else is triggered by the `TaskScheduler` when it polls `SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource`. With the `fixed-interval` we will have only one polling task at a time. Since code I've shown before is blocking, we don't have any "in-process" files until they all will be downloaded to the local dir from the remote one. That is how it works. Everything rest must be proved by particular test-case. At least share DEBUG logs for `org.springframework.integration`.

Comment: as mentioned, the first step is to download all the file from remote dir and next step is to start reading those files to process. so how to conclude that the first step is over ( by downloading all the files) ?

Comment: OK. What does the `downloading` mean for you? The `<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>` has `local-directory`. Remote files are downloaded to that dir and only after that they are started to be polled from there as a `payload` for message to the `channel`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My question still is in my below code, after adapter is started, the flow immediately completes & exits the tasklet execute block. So the next step continues to look for files present in the local-dir. But the files are not yet downloaded at all. So should we manually add a Thread.slepp() to allow the async process to complete the download ? or is there any other way ?

Comment: Added Code snippet in EDIT of question at last : DownloadingTasklet

Comment: That is what I meant. The `sftpInbondAdapter` does its work in the `TaskScheduler` thread but not that `main`. I am not not what is your goal in that `execute()`, but if you would like to wait for something from that async integration flow, you should consider some *reply* from there. For example `QueueChannel` and `<aggregator>` to collect all donwloaded files and `<gateway>` with `List<File> donwloaded()`  method for that channel to wait for. But is fully different story and doesn't relate to the question about SFTP async problem. There is no problem, just some target application design flaw

Comment: True. Thanks Bilan. One last query. Should I worry to stop the adapter that was started explicitly ? or let the spring bean cycle shut it down? any resource locking due to not stopping it? Even though we dont expect some more files at the remote location .

Comment: Yes, Spring will take care about it in the end of application. Typically we start all the components and don't care about their idle work. Or you can stop when you are sure that you don't need it any more. I guess in the end of your job would be enough, if you already figure out how to block it until download finish.